# Pretty Printing on Flask and uWSGI

Tags: json, nginx, flask, uwsgi, pretty-print

My Python Flask application display JSON calls in pretty print when running in development box.

However, after it is deployed to a production with nginx/uWSGI, the pretty print is lost.

How do I maintain the pretty printing for Flask app deployed on nginx/uWSGI

Answer (score 3):

Flask's [`jsonify`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify) function will pretty print output by default.  This is disabled during AJAX requests or if `JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR` is configured to be `False`.  Other JSON dump functions besides `jsonify` will not pretty print unless told to.  There will not be any difference on production versus development unless you have changed this configuration option.